# Simple html link wont work

Tags: html, css

I'm having difficulty pinpointing whats preventing the following link from working.

I chose a random link (w3schools) to test it before I linked it to what its meant for.

I thought the problem may have to do with the CSS.

```css
ul {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #994f00;
}

#innerNav {
  /*adding a relative or absolute here will break sticky*/
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1300px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: -1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <!-- HTML 5 -->
<html lang="en">
<body>
 <div class= 'wrapper'>
   <div id = 'innerNav'>
         <li>
           <ul><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/" target="_top">The Door</a></ul>
           <ul>Mr Pointy</ul>
           <ul>Block Rain</ul>
          </li>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But even when I comment out the last line of the innerNav, the link still doesn't work (clicking it doesn't open anything).

Any ideas?

also my git files for this is:

[Portfolio](https://github.com/DravionV/My-Portfolio)

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Try swapping your li's and ul's

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. The live demo doesn't work because Stackoverflow sandboxes demos so you can't `target="_top"` but if I remove that then it bounces off the W3Schools rules against putting their pages in iframes. Without the security restrictions SO enforces, it would work fine.

Comment: j08691 tried that, it didn't work.

Comment: ryan when you hover your mouse over the word that has a link to it, it doesnt link.

Comment: Try running your page through a validator to fix all the errors. https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input. In the meantime, your example works fine if you correct the errors in it. What you've posted here is insufficient however (why is there a rule `#innerNav` and no element with that ID?). We need a [mcve] to see what you see.

Comment: I think there's missing HTML here. It works through a plain old HTML file on my end. Well, when the `ul` and `li` invalid html is fixed (as in the answer provided below). Please provide more information and code, as this code would work.

Comment: Pasting this code into an editor works fine on my end too, even with the ul and li tags being reversed.  What are you editing this with outside of Stack Overflow, and is there any other code?

Comment: I copied your HTML from your github page exactly, and it works. Of course, this is without styling. So, it's probably a layering issue with your css. Check z-index and all that to be sure something isn't on top. Please learn how to use chrome developer tools. You should be able to catch this in minutes of changing a z-index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the link and everything to do with the fact that you have the `z-index` of your `#innerNav` set to -1.  So you are covering your navigation up with the `.wrapper`.  So just remove the z-index from the innerNav completely or just set it to 1.

PS the markup for this is invalid as well you may want to look up the correct markup for an unordered list it should be as follows:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

For some reason you have it backwards with `<ul>` nested inside of `<li>` it should be the other way around.

Comment: Also, learn how to use chrome developer tools, or the tools provided by your favourite browser as well - https://developer.chrome.com/devtools